# Is there a way to update the label of the custom fields in a managed package using code?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

How to update the field label from apex class? I have a managed package and want to update the Label of the Package field from Apex class without using Translation Workbench in the subscriber org. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Label attribute of a Custom Field contained in a managed package [is not subscriber-editable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm), which includes interventions made by Apex code running in a subscriber org. Note that Label is listed under Developer Editable, which means you can change the label in your managed package and ship the change in a new version, but cannot directly alter it in a subscriber org.

You won't be able to change the actual field label, so as far as I'm aware Translation Workbench will be your only recourse.